# c++ nlohmann json - how to iterate / find a nested object

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am trying to iterate over a nested json, using nlohmann::json.  My json object is below:

```
{
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2
    "three": {
        "three.one": 3.1
    },
}
```

I am trying to iterate and /or find nested objects.  But, it seems there is no default support for it.  It looks like I have to iterate over each sub-object by creating another loop, or call the fn recursively for every sub-object.

My following piece of code, and its result indicate, that only top level iteration possible.

```
void findNPrintKey (json src, const std::string& key) {
  auto result = src.find(key);
  if (result != src.end()) {
    std::cout << "Entry found for : " << result.key() << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Entry not found for : " << key << std::endl ;
  }
}


void enumerate () {

  json j = json::parse("{  \"one\" : 1 ,  \"two\" : 2, \"three\" : { \"three.one\" : 3.1 } } ");
  //std::cout << j.dump(4) << std::endl;

  // Enumerate all keys (including sub-keys -- not working)
  for (auto it=j.begin(); it!=j.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << "key: " << it.key() << " : " << it.value() << std::endl;
  }

  // find a top-level key
  findNPrintKey(j, "one");
  // find a nested key
  findNPrintKey(j, "three.one");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  enumerate();
  return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
ravindrnathsMBP:utils ravindranath$ ./a.out 
key: one : 1
key: three : {"three.one":3.1}
key: two : 2
Entry found for : one
Entry not found for : three.one
```

So, is there a recursive iteration available, or do we have to do this ourselves, using is_object() method?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Indeed, iteration does not recurse and there is no library function for this (yet). What about:

```
#include "json.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using json = nlohmann::json;

template<class UnaryFunction>
void recursive_iterate(const json& j, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for(auto it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->is_structured())
        {
            recursive_iterate(*it, f);
        }
        else
        {
            f(it);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    json j = {{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}, {"three", {"three.one", 3.1}}};
    recursive_iterate(j, [](json::const_iterator it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    });
}
```

The output is:

```
1
"three.one"
3.1
2
```

Comment: Is there a better way since 2017? In fact, I'm interested in DOM-like traversal of the tree where I use keys to decide about further recursive descent. However, can't call key() on array on certain types of nodes and can't easily check for iterator.

Comment: You may want to try the [`items()`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_afe3e137ace692efa08590d8df40f58dd.html#afe3e137ace692efa08590d8df40f58dd) function.

Comment: Is there a way to access a node’s parent as you traverse the nodes (items) in the json tree?

Comment: Not unless you store it while traversing.

Comment: I've provided the solution for accessing the parents in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a spin off from the accepted answer, which gives you the added benefit of having the parent keys (in addition to the iterator) as you "walk" the json tree.

The parent keys are provided in a list format to easily iterate over them directly. I've also provided the means to convert that list of strings into a "nested json key" (i.e. a `json_pointer`). That is an object you can use to directly access that k/v pair when performing assorted operations built into nlohmann::json.

### Utility functions

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

#include "nlohmann.hpp"

using JsonIter = nlohmann::json::const_iterator;

typedef std::list<std::string> JsonKeys;

std::string toJsonStringKey( const JsonKeys &keys )
{
    static const std::string JSON_KEY_DELIM( "/" );
    std::string s;
    for( auto k : keys ) s.append( JSON_KEY_DELIM + k );
    return s;
}

nlohmann::json::json_pointer toJsonPointerKey( const JsonKeys &keys )
{ return nlohmann::json::json_pointer( toJsonStringKey( keys ) ); }

nlohmann::json::json_pointer toJsonPointerKey(
    const JsonKeys &parentKeys, JsonIter it )
{
    JsonKeys allKeys( parentKeys );
    allKeys.push_back( it.key() );
    return nlohmann::json::json_pointer( toJsonStringKey( allKeys ) );
}

typedef std::function< void( const JsonKeys &parentKeys,
    nlohmann::json::const_iterator it )> WalkJsonCallBack;
void walkJson( const nlohmann::json &jsonObj, JsonKeys &parentKeys,
    WalkJsonCallBack callback )
{
    for( auto it( jsonObj.begin() ); it != jsonObj.end(); ++it )
    {
        if( it->is_structured() )
        {
            parentKeys.push_back( it.key() );
            walkJson( *it, parentKeys, callback );
            parentKeys.pop_back();
        }
        else callback( parentKeys, it );
    }
}
```

### Example implementation

```
const nlohmann::json parsed( nlohmann::json::parse( raw ) ); 
JsonKeys parentKeys;
walkJson( parsed, parentKeys, []( const JsonKeys &parentKeys, JsonIter it )
{
    // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE

    // Example of getting a pointer key..
    const auto key( toJsonPointerKey( parentKeys, it ) );
    // Now, do whatever with that key...

});
```

### Sample Data

And here's the op's sample data, after adding a few more fields and nestings:

```
const std::string testData(
    "{  \"one\" : 1 , \"two\" : 2, "
       "\"three\" : { "
        " \"three.one\" : 3.1, "
        " \"three.two\" : { \"three.two.one\" : 3.21, \"three.two.two\" : 3.22 }, "
        " \"three.three\": { \"three.three.one\" : 3.31, \"three.three.two\" : 3.32 }, "
        " \"three.four\": 3.4, "
        " \"three.five\": { \"three.five.one\" : 3.51, \"three.five.two\" : 3.52 } "
        "}, "
        "\"four\" : 4"
    "} " );
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't really seem better than the one that the literal author of the library posted (Niels Lohmann, e.g. `nlohmann`). `std::list` is generally terrible due to pointer-chasing, and `std::function` is an allocating function that can lead to worse performance than the `recursive_iterate` implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. I would like to improve this. Niel's posted solution does not provide the parent keys. In the comments, he basically says for people figure that for themselves. That's the point of this. Instead of std::list, what type of collection do you suggest?  I was just keeping it simple. And why would that really matter in the context of parsing json? How deep of a nesting should we worry about?  That list isn't too likely to have more than a handful of items, and one isn't typically iterating over all that many json entries.

Comment: Also what type would you recommend I use here instead of std::function?

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers, this is testsed:

```
typedef std::list<std::string> json_keys;
typedef std::function< void(const json_keys& key, const json& it)> json_recursive_iterate_callback;

void json_recursive_iterate(const json& js, json_keys& keys, json_recursive_iterate_callback cb)
{
    for (auto& [key, val] : js.items())
    {
        keys.push_back(key);

        if (val.is_structured())
            json_recursive_iterate(val, keys, cb);          
        else
            cb(keys, val);          

        keys.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
json_keys keys;
json_recursive_iterate(body, keys, [&](const json_keys& keys, const json& it)
{               
    std::string key;            
    for (auto k : keys) key.append("/" + k);

    std::cout << key << " = " << it << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much just a "compressed" version of my answer, with features stripped out e.g. the toJsonPointerKey functions I offered as additional conveniences.

Comment: If you would like to "advance the cause" here, perhaps you might address the criticisms my answer received with regard to optimization (for those who need to shave microseconds processing json).