# c++ nlohmann json - how to test nested object is existent or empty

Tags: c++, nested, nlohmann-json

I have a nested Json like this:

```
   string strJson = "{
  "Header":

    {"Version":"V0.00.01","ID":"1000","Name":"SetEnvValues"}


  ,
  "Data":

    {"Temp":0.00,"rH":0.00,"CO2":0.00,"O2":0.00 }



}";
```

Now I want to test if there is an Element "rH" existent. For example, if I only have in the Data Objekt one value "Temp", how can I test which values are existent? Is this possible without exception handling?

```
{
"Header":

{"Version":"V0.00.01","ID":"1000","Name":"SetEnvValues"}


,
"Data":

{"Temp":0.00 }



}
```

I tried it with count, but it seems this wont work for nested objects:

```
jsonReceivedEnvValues = json::parse(strJson);
int count = jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].count("Bla");
```

This returns always one, I think because it only tests the "Data" Object, and not the deeper nested ones.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934851/c-nlohmann-json-how-to-iterate-find-a-nested-object). You can also use `find` and compare to the `end` iterator.

Comment: If I try this, I get the following exception:  

_what():  [json.exception.invalid_iterator.212] cannot compare iterators of different containers_              Code: `if(jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].find("Bla") != jsonReceivedEnvValues.end())
  cout << "Entry Bla found!" << endl;
 else
  cout << "Entry Bla not found!" << endl;`

Comment: That's because you are trying to compare iterators of `jsonReceivedEnvValues` and `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"]`. They are 2 different containers. You need to do `if(jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].find("Bla") != jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].end())`

Comment: Ok, I tried this on to, but it returns `true`, so I think this call is not using the find instruction. I found something else, it seems that `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"]["Bla"].is_null();` works, it retruns `false`  if the second object is not existing in the Json document.

Comment: `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"]["Bla"]` will create a new object if it does not exist. Why not just read the [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#json-as-first-class-data-type). You have all the information you need there.

Comment: I didn't reproduce your problem. When I invoke `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].count("Bla");` and the keyword `Bla` doesn't exist under `Data` it returns 0, which is correct. Otherwise it returns 1.

Comment: int count = jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].count("Bla");

Comment: @super: You saved my day, in my tests I accidently created an Object with the following line: `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"]["Bla"].end();`Because of that all my tests with count failed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"].count("Bla")`. Make sure that you don't accidentally create the object you're looking for; for instance, `jsonReceivedEnvValues["Data"]["Bla"].is_null();` creates an object *["Bla"]* in *["Data"]*